# Expand JSON with unknown keys to rows with MySQL JSON_TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL 8.0.22 JSON column containing objects with keys that aren't known in advance:

```
'{"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}'
'{"e": 4, "k": 5}'
```

I want to use `JSON_TABLE` to expand these values into multiple rows containing key value pairs:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 2 |
| z | 3 |
| e | 4 |
| k | 5 |

The difficulty of course is that the keys aren't known *a priori*. The best thing I've come up with is...

```sql
SET @json_doc = '{"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}';

SELECT a.seq, b.k, a.v

    FROM

    JSON_TABLE(
        @json_doc,
        "$.*"
        COLUMNS(
            seq FOR ordinality,
            v INT PATH "$"
        )
    ) AS a,

    JSON_TABLE(
        JSON_KEYS(@json_doc),
        "$[*]"
        COLUMNS(
            seq FOR ordinality,
            k CHAR(1) PATH "$"
        )
    ) AS b

    WHERE a.seq = b.seq;
```

This feels strange because it uses two `JSON_TABLE` calls, does a cross join on the values and keys, then keeps the ones that align. I'd like to find a simpler query like this...

```sql
SELECT a.seq, b.k, a.v

    FROM
    
    JSON_TABLE(
        @json_doc,
        "$.*"
        COLUMNS(
            seq FOR ordinality,
            k CHAR(1) PATH "?"  -- <-- what do I put here to find each key?
            v INT PATH "$"
        )
    ) AS a,
```

I know this problem can probably be solved with CTEs or a numbers table and `JSON_EXTRACT`. But, I'd like to find something performant and readable if possible.

Comment: I needed only sequence , its worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  enumarete by using `ROW_NUMBER()` window function while determining the key values through use of `JSON_KEYS()`, and then extract the respective keys by using `JSON_EXTRACT()` from the arrays we got such as

```
WITH k AS
(
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `jsdata` ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn,
       JSON_KEYS(`jsdata`) AS jk
  FROM `tab` AS t
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(`jsdata`,'$.*' COLUMNS (value INT PATH '$')) j
)
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jk, CONCAT('$[',rn-1,']'))) AS "key", 
       value
  FROM k
```

**or** use the following query as being more straightforward

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(
       JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(`jsdata`), 
                    CONCAT('$[',
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `jsdata` ORDER BY value DESC)-1,
                    ']'))
                   ) AS "key", value
  FROM `tab` AS t
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(`jsdata`,'$.*' COLUMNS (value INT PATH '$')) j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18b712d712c56db01aba9bf760784441)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `JSON_EXTRACT` directly after you got the `JSON_KEYS` as rows:

```sql
  WITH j AS (
      SELECT CAST('{"a": 1, "b": "-1", "c": null}' AS JSON) o UNION ALL
      SELECT CAST('{"x": 2, "y": "-2", "z": null}' AS JSON)
  )
SELECT k, JSON_EXTRACT(j.o, CONCAT('$."', jt.k, '"')) v
  FROM j
     , JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(o), '$[*]' COLUMNS (k VARCHAR(200) PATH '$')) jt;
```

The answer by Barbaros can solve your problem with the demo data you provided, but it may not get what you want if your json objects have same value under different keys.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as EricW's answer but without the CTE and with an explicit cross join...

```sql
SELECT k, JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, concat('$.', k)) as v
FROM the_table t
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    json_keys(json_data),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(k VARCHAR(10) path '$')
) t2;
```